# HANA: How to properly "CREATE SEQUENCE START WITH" with a dynamic start value?

Tags: sql, sequence, hana

I want to create a SQL statement for a sequence that will dynamically set the starting value.

The following SQL statement runs into an error.

```
CREATE SEQUENCE id_seq START WITH (SELECT MAX(identificationnumber)+1 FROM newsletter_status);
```

> Could not execute 'CREATE SEQUENCE id_seq START WITH SELECT MAX(identificationnumber) FROM newsletter_status'Error: (dberror) [257]: sql syntax error: incorrect syntax near "SELECT": line 1 col 41 (at pos 42)

I should mention that `SELECT MAX(identificationnumber) FROM newsletter_status` works properly and returns a number.

Trying to extract the value first into a variable does not help too.

```
DO
BEGIN
    DECLARE identificationnumber_max BIGINT;
    SELECT MAX(identificationnumber) INTO identificationnumber_max FROM newsletter_status;
    CREATE SEQUENCE id_seq START WITH :identificationnumber_max + 1;
END;
```

> Could not execute 'DO BEGIN DECLARE identificationnumber_max BIGINT; SELECT MAX(identificationnumber) INTO ...'Error: (dberror) [257]: sql syntax error: incorrect syntax near ":identificationnumber_max": line 5 col 38 (at pos 184)

When I do the following I will get my desired result.

```
DO
BEGIN
    DECLARE identificationnumber_max BIGINT;
    SELECT MAX(identificationnumber) INTO identificationnumber_max FROM newsletter_status;
    EXEC 'CREATE SEQUENCE id_seq START WITH ' || :identificationnumber_max + 1 || ';';
END;
```

But this looks very bulky and complex for a thing that should be really obvious and easy to implement. This reduces readability. Is there a simpler way to do what I want?

Comment: What happens if you declare it as "INT"?

Comment: @Scratte nothing changes

Comment: I see. According to [SQL Error Codes](http://sap.optimieren.de/hana/hana/html/_jsql_error_codes.html) error code 257 is a "SQL syntax error". I'm thinking that perhaps variables cannot be used with DDL statements.

Comment: I'm not a HANA expert. But it looks familiar. `CREATE SEQUENCE` is a DDL (data definition language) statement as opposed to a DML (data manipulation language) statement. DDL statement do no support subselects or variables (like `:identificationnumber_max `).

Comment: Interesting.... But... there is a workaround then with my last code sample.)

Comment: Yes, that's the correct approach, using `EXEC` for a dynamic executing. It works because the variable is part of the procedural language generating a string, and not part of the DML statement.

Comment: What is the use case for this? Setting the possible range of values for a sequence is commonly done once only at creation time.

Answer (score 2):

If you check [the documentation](https://help.sap.com/viewer/4fe29514fd584807ac9f2a04f6754767/2.0.04/en-US/20d509277519101489029c064d468c5d.html) and [notation definition](https://help.sap.com/viewer/4fe29514fd584807ac9f2a04f6754767/2.0.04/en-US/209e0cde751910149114be53649a1fb7.html), you'll find this:

```
START WITH <start_value>

<start_value> ::= <signed_integer>
```

This way there's no possibility to have any expression. I cannot find any reasonable argument for this, because there's a possibility to specify subquery in the `reset by` part, so the sequence still will depend on the tables involved and the same mechanism may be used for `starts with`.

Anyway, you may consider to use `reset by`:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE id_seq
START WITH 1
INCREMENT BY 1
RESET BY (
  SELECT MAX(identificationnumber)+1
  FROM newsletter_status
)
```

Comment: Thank you for the yidea. But suddenly this is not acceptable for us. The reset by will be evaluated by every DB restart. Id deletion is performed sometiems in our app. This two events could lead that some ids will be created twice. We want to avoid that.

Comment: @SGTechEdge The best way to avoid ID reuse would be to not delete IDs in the first place but only mark them as deleted. If you want to hard-delete the data for privacy reasons, just `NULL` out all the non-key fields. Due to the way the column store engine of HANA works, those entries will create next to no storage space.